# Induced map from the universal cover of the base space to the Teichmuller space of the fiber is holomorphic

Tags: complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, teichmueller-theory

Let $\phi:X\to Y$ be a submersion and holomorphic map with not every two fibers are biholomorphic, where $X$ a compact complex surface, $Y$ is a Riemann surface. Let $\pi:U\to Y$ be the universal covering space of $Y$ and $T$ be a Teichmuller space of Teichmuller structures on a compact topological surface of genus same as the genus of the fiber of $p$. Then we get a map $f:U\to T$, s.t. $u\in U$ is mapped to a point of $T$ representing the complex structure of $\phi^{-1}(\pi(u))$.  Then why is $f$ holomorphic?

Comment: I'm a little rusty, but I don't think it matters if all the fibers are biholomorphic, because holomorphy is a purely local property. So you have by Ehressman's theorem that in a neighborhood of any point an identitfication of the form $X = X_0 \times Y$, where $Y$ has been replaced with a neighborhood of a point of interest, and $X_0$ denotes the fiber over this point. Now my guess is that you can say something about the deformations on $Y$ using period coordinates on Teichmuller space.

Comment: @AlfredYerger fibers are not biholomorphic is an assumption. This is question is actaully from the first theorem here: [Kas68] A. Kas: [On deformations of a certain type of irregular algebraic surface](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2373484)